# Spring won't load config on client app (Spring Cloud Config Server)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-config

My config service does work fine. Here is the application.properties

```
server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri= file:///${user.home}/config-repo
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
security.user.name=root
security.user.password=s3cr3t
server.servlet.context-path=/config-service
```

And When doing 
    curl http://root:s3cr3t@localhost:8888/config-service/my-service/development

The results are fine and I can see all the properties:

```
{"name":"my-service","profiles":["development"]...
```

However, the client isn't loading the config. 
Here is the bootstrap.properties

```
spring.application.name=my-service
spring.profiles.active=development
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888/config-service
spring.cloud.config.username=root
spring.cloud.config.password=s3cr3t
```

Here is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>

    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>my-service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>my-service</name>
<description>Desc</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.55</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--test-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Here is the log:

```
    2634 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'spring.application.name' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties' with value of type String 
2638 [main] DEBUG o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Loading source class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapImportSelectorConfiguration 
2664 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Activated activeProfiles development 
2664 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Profiles already activated, '[development]' will not be applied 
2664 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Loaded config file 'file:/C:/my-service/target/classes/bootstrap.properties' (classpath:/bootstrap.properties) 
2665 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@44c03695 
2677 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor' 
2692 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' 
2810 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry' 
2914 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer' 
2918 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor' 
2919 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata' 
2920 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory' 
2922 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor' 
2923 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor' 
2925 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor' 
2927 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'configurationPropertiesBeans' 
2927 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' 
2932 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bd2aa01c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying) 
2947 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'bootstrapImportSelectorConfiguration' 
2947 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.config.GcpConfigBootstrapConfiguration' 
2949 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'spring.cloud.gcp.config-org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.config.GcpConfigProperties' 
2953 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'spring.cloud.gcp.config-org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.config.GcpConfigProperties' via constructor to bean named 'environment' 
2957 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'spring.application.name' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties' with value of type String 
2957 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'spring.application.name' in PropertySource 'environmentProperties' with value of type String 
2966 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration' 
2969 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'spring.cloud.config-org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapProperties' 
2971 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration' 
2973 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'encrypt-org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.KeyProperties' 
2975 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'environmentDecryptApplicationListener' 
2980 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinder' 
2980 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'configurationPropertiesRebinder' via factory method to bean named 'configurationPropertiesBeans' 
2986 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration' 
3002 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener - 


============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor' (OnBeanCondition)

   ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration#configurationPropertiesBeans matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration#configurationPropertiesRebinder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor' (OnClassCondition)

   PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration#propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------

   EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.RsaEncryptionConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - Keystore nor key found in Environment (EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.KeyCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.security.rsa.crypto.RsaSecretEncryptor' (OnClassCondition)

   EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.VanillaEncryptionConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingClass found unwanted class 'org.springframework.security.rsa.crypto.RsaSecretEncryptor' (OnClassCondition)

   GcpConfigBootstrapConfiguration#googleConfigPropertySourceLocator:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.cloud.gcp.config.enabled=true) did not find property 'enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


----------------------
```

But properties are not being loaded, and there is no exception shown that's related to this. I don't see mention of spring.cloud.config.uri in the logs.

Comment: There are logs in the config client about looking up property sources, can you post them?

Comment: I have posted it

Comment: It should have lines like this https://gist.github.com/spencergibb/e2468e7eaa42ccc874e70753631f124a, can you show your dependencies?

Comment: I've added them in the decription

Comment: thanks! Looking at that log I saw a class I was missing, so I found the missing dep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to spencergibb who pointed at ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator, so I realized I was missing this in my pom file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the starter

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```